# What is module in run configuration of Android Studio?

Tags: macos, android-studio

I'm new in Android development. I using Android Studio on Mac OSX. I create a new project with a master & details template. I try to run an app in emulator but what does the module dropdownbox in run configuration mean? And how do I turn on the preview mode in multiple devices like in this [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e0fXuyL0xVU)?

Answer (score 3):

As I have just answered here:

[Project management IntelliJ IDEA / Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16604284/project-management-intellij-idea-android-studio/16623727#16623727)

> You can see a Module in Intellij as a Project in Eclipse.
>
> And a Project in Intellij is the sum of modules that make your project run.
>
> When you create a module from existing sources, Intellij will add it's module.iml configuration file to the specified location. Then all the configuration you have done on this Library module will be re-usable when importing this module in another Intellij project.

The module you will specify in the running configuration is the one Android Studio should look for AndroidManifest and main activity to launch after installing your application.

You may have one main module and several library modules. (So called Android Library Project in ADT)