# Updating Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, installation, updating

The Android Studio version I have installed is a bit old now so it cannot automatically update. I have to manually download the full version and update. So I did download it from [here](http://tools.android.com/download/studio/canary/latest/).

My question is do I have to uninstall the old version first in order to install the new version? And also I don't see a setup.exe or anything in the latest version I downloaded. How do I update this properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that I did have to uninstall the previous version and re-install.

There were some other problems I had as well regarding android support libraries, SDK locations for imported eclipse projects.

In case it helps you can find my solution to another question regarding project issues at https://stackoverflow.com/a/24440211/499448

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the response. In the local.properties file, I have this line `sdk.dir=C\:/Program Files (x86)/Android/android-studio/sdk` Do you mean to do something like this `sdk.dir=C\://Program Files (x86)//Android//android-studio//sdk`?

Comment: It should be ``sdk.dir=C\:\\Program Files (x86)\\Android\\android-studio\\sdk``.

Comment: I uninstalled the old version and installed the new one. I'm just starting Android development so I only had one little project. So instead of going through all that hassle, I simply recreated that project from the new Android Studio version. But when I connect my device and try to run it, I get the **ADB not responding** error. I tried [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18060360/1077789) but didn't work. Any idea on how to resolve this?

Comment: I even added a path variable like [this](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/38324) but to no avail.

Comment: Okay, I uninstalled Android Studio again along with the folders created by it in Users and all. Reinstalled it and now everything's working fine. Ugh! This is what I hate about using Android tools. One small change and everything gets screwed up -_-

Comment: Glad you sorted it, Android Studio is a bit fiddly, but it is in Beta so its not surprising