# Can't import an eclipse project into android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

I am trying to learn android in android studio.Now i imported an eclipse project in android studio and now while trying to run it it is not building.Some problems in gradle may be..

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
```

> Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 8 cannot be smaller than version L declared in library com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.0-rc1

my build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'android'
```

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19.1.0"

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.practise"
    minSdkVersion 8
    targetSdkVersion 19
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        runProguard false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:+'
compile 'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:+'
}
```

Can anyone help me to find out the problem??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your dependencies

```
dependencies {
 compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.1.0'
 compile 'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:19.1.0'
}
```

Using the `+`, you are getting the last release.

Currently the last release is the `compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21` and it has a minSdk='L' because it is a preview release.

Use it **only to test** the android 'L' preview.

Comment: do u have account [http://commonsware.com/] @Gabriele Mariotti..i need the latest version of busy coders guide but its not free.I don't have that much money..can u give it to me if u can??Because my android studio learning is haulted..It would be great for me if i get the book..

Comment: I suggest you contacting the author, explaining your case.

Comment: i have tried to contact..do u have account there??can u do something for me??

Answer (score 0):

Try editing the following line to your Android Manifest file, like so:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21+' 
}
```

Then your project should build.

Comment: it is not working..actually i am not cleared by your answer..i am editing my question..

Comment: Thanks for sharing your manifest file. Try updated the dependencies, like I stated above.

Comment: Error:A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:_debugCompile'.
   > Could not find com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.0.
     Required by:
         practise:app:unspecified
This error occurred...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24436678/manifest-merger-failed-uses-sdkminsdkversion-10-cannot-be-smaller-than-versio

Comment: do u have account [http://commonsware.com/] @EmC..i need the latest version of busy coders guide but its not free.I don't have that much money..can u give it to me if u can??Because my android studio learning is haulted..It would be great for me if i get the book..

Answer (score 0):

Change your dependencies in app/build.gradle to lower version

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 20
buildToolsVersion "20.0.0"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.eusecom.snowsmsden"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 20
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        runProguard false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:20.+'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:20.+'
}
```

Comment: do u have account [http://commonsware.com/] @eurosecom..i need the latest version of busy coders guide but its not free.I don't have that much money..can u give it to me if u can??Because my android studio learning is haulted..It would be great for me if i get the book..