# Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 14

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, android-5.0-lollipop

Since downloading the latest SDK and installing Android Studio, my project fails to build. I get the following message:

```
Error:Gradle: Execution failed for task ':SampleProject:processProdDebugManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 14 cannot be smaller than version L declared in library com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.0-rc1
```

Comment: I am having same error Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 19 cannot be smaller than version 19 declared in library com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.0-rc1

Comment: I'm getting the same exception minSdkVersion 15 cannot be smaller than version 15. The SDK Build tools has been updated so I guess its a bug in Android Studio and the new Build tools

Comment: It seems to be a bug: [code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=72430](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=72430)
The fix for now is to comment out a line in the maven-metadata.xml

Comment: possible duplicate of [Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 8 cannot be smaller](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24718824/manifest-merger-failed-uses-sdkminsdkversion-8-cannot-be-smaller)

Answer (score 312, accepted):

**Note: This has been updated to reflect the release of API 21, Lollipop. Be sure to download the latest SDK.**

In one of my modules I had the following in build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:+'
}
```

Changing this to

```
dependencies {
    // do not use dynamic updating.
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.0' 
}
```

fixed the issue.

Make sure you're not doing a general inclusion of `com.android.support:support-v4:+` or any other support libraries (v7, v13, appcompat, etc), anywhere in your project.

I'd assume the problem is `v4:+` picks up the <s>release candidate (21.0.0-rc1)</s> latest L release which obviously requires the L SDK.

**Edit:**

If you need to use the new views (CardView, RecyclerView, and Palette), the following should work:

```
compile "com.android.support:cardview-v7:21.0.0"
compile "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:21.0.0"
compile "com.android.support:palette-v7:21.0.0"
```

(Credit to EddieRingle on /androiddev - http://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/297xli/howto_use_the_v21_support_libs_on_older_versions/)

**Another Edit**

Be sure to see @murtuza's answer below regarding appcompat-v7 and upvote if it helps!

Comment: What about a library compiled from Maven ? How to exclude the "old" dependancy ?

Comment: @Arnaud not sure there's a way around that. Somebody else will have to comment on that. I'd suggest opening a pull request and/or issue if the project is open source.

Comment: @Arnaud compile("blah:blah:bla") {exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'}

Comment: Note that to use CardView, RecyclerView and Palette, you will also have to alter your Manifest to avoid the merge conflict gradle throws.
See this link for details: http://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/297xli/howto_use_the_v21_support_libs_on_older_versions/

Comment: In my case I had to remove it from local maven as gauravsapiens commented.

Comment: worked, thanks. found this as well http://google-android-studio.blogspot.co.uk/2013/10/fixing-gradle-after-update-to-android.html

Comment: Never, ever, suggest people to use + in the dependency version.
ALWAYS specify the exact version of the library you want to use (or is available at the time you write the code).

Even 20.+ is bad.

And if a library you depends on follow this BAD practice consider excluding its dependency and providing your own version of that dependency.

This makes your build reproducible at any time.

Please improve your answer buy removing your suggestion to use + in the dependency version.

Comment: What @DanieleSegato said. Do not recommend dynamic versioning ever. It's bad practices.

Comment: @XavierDucrohet @DanieleSegato, I updated the answer. What should the v7 support library version be? `com.android.support:cardview-v7:20` or variations I tried don't seem to work. I changed the previous to `20.0.0` (which seems to work fine).

Comment: @loeschg those libraries are only available in 21.0.0-rc1 so you should put that. When we update to rc2 or the final version you'll need to manually update it but that's better than never doing it, forgetting about it and later be hit when we release 22-rc1 which breaks the project somehow.

Comment: @DanieleSegato said this right. It's bad practice to use '+' as identifier for future versions. I have been using compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.0' and this fixed the issue. But do not forget to update the **support library version** from SDK manager.

Comment: compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:22.2.0' this is the compatible cardview

Answer (score 69):

Also, in case you are importing the appcompat-v7 library make sure you tag a version number at the end of it like so:

```
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.+'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.+'
```

After only changing the support-v4 version, I still received the error:

> Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 15 cannot be smaller than version L declared in library com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.0-rc1

It was a bit confusing because it looks like v4 is still the problem, but, in fact, restricting the appcompat v7 version fixed the problem.

Comment: Good catch! none of my v7 had the version on them either.

Comment: and also the same thing for support v13 )

Comment: I had a mismatch of appcompat_v7 too, `buildToolsVersion '20.0.0'` in my `android{}` and `compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:20.0+'` in my `dependencies {}` was not the same, so I made them the same (as shown here).

Comment: It is a bad practice to use **+** identifier for future versions. Specify the exact version. I suggest to update the **'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.+'** to this **'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.0.0'** or which is the latest one. If you still face issues **try updating support library** from SDK manager.

Answer (score 56):

**Solution 1:**

Change uses-sdk to `<uses-sdk tools:node="replace" />` and add      `xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"`
in `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.demo.android"
    android:versionCode="16"
    android:versionName="3.3.1">
    .
    .
    <uses-sdk tools:node="replace" />
    .
    .
</manifest>
```

Make sure you use gradle 0.11 and above to use Manifest merger.

**Solution 2:**

- Change     `compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:+'` to  `compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:20.+'` in `build.gradle`. This will prevent gradle from using 
  `v4:21.0.0` that requires version L.
- However, if your any of your external dependencies uses the same. You will probably have to wait for them to update the same.

**Solution 3:**

- Remove/Comment `<version>21.0.0-rc1</version>` in your file `<android-sdk>/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support-v4/maven-metadata.xml`
- Repeat the same for support-v7

Comment: In my case I also had to remove the appcompat-v7 equivalent.

Comment: Yes do not provide solution 2 as an option. Proper dependency management (using the right version), or using resolution strategy is the right solution. Editing the maven repo is only delaying the problem until a new repo is released.

Comment: Solution 1 + 3 saved my life :)

Comment: First option works! I would suggest you to add some details about why this to be done.

Answer (score 25):

```
<uses-sdk tools:node="replace" />
```

No longer works.

change `uses-sdk` to

```
<uses-sdk tools:overrideLibrary="com.packagename.of.libary.with.conflict" />
```

and add
`xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"` 
in the       AndroidManifest.xml file

Comment: As outlined here: http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide/manifest-merger

Comment: Thank you @userM1433372 , upvoted for saving my day :)

Answer (score 11):

The problem still arises with transitive dependencies. Gradle offers a way to force the usage of a specific version of a dependency.

For example you can add something like:

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy {
        force 'com.android.support:support-v4:20.+'
        force 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:20.+'
    }
}
```

to your build.gradle.

If you want to learn more about gradle resolution strategies refer to this guide http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.artifacts.ResolutionStrategy.html

I found this while reading the corresponding issue which I will link [here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=72430)

Comment: Thanks! Easier than putting exclude in every dependency :)

Answer (score 8):

Adding to the correct answers above, the problem still might occur due to library nesting. In this case, try as the example below:

```
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:20.+'
compile ('com.github.chrisbanes.actionbarpulltorefresh:extra-abs:+') { // example
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module:'support-v4'
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module:'appcompat-v7'
}
```

Answer (score 8):

In the build.gradle file, It was by default compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:+' so when you build the gradle projecit would consider, com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.0-rc1 because of the recent L developer preview release.

Make changes in the following line and it will resolve the issue.
Change

```
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:+'
```

to

```
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:20.+'
```

Similarly when using v7-appcompat support library, make the change from

`compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'`

to

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:20.+'.
```

Answer (score 7):

for people building hybrid apps using cordova CLI, this command will help:

```
cordova build android -- --minSdkVersion=15
```

yes it uses double double dashes as you saw it.

Comment: Does this resolve the actual problem? No. It only works like that, but with `cordova run android` it fails.

Comment: @lonut do you know what actual problem is ?

Comment: In my case the problem is a plugin I'm using called `cordova-plugin-facebook4`. Unistalling it makes `cordova run android` work just fine. Unfortunately I didn't found any solution to this anywhere. I manually tried to add the `minSdkVersion` myself in the `AndroidManifest` but is being overwritten. Still trying to figure it out.

Comment: @lonut I am using same plugin in some app I am working on, let me know if I can help. However you need to review the build.gradle file, maybe if you provide extra info I can help.

Comment: I finally solved it by changing the `minSdk` version to `15` in `config.xml`. The line: `<preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="14" />`. This way the `AndroidManifest` file is being updated also with the new version.

Answer (score 6):

For people facing this issue in the **Android Studio** beta, the accepted answer didn't solve my problem. Importing a project downloaded from GitHub, I had the following in my build.gradle file of app giving an error in question:

```
 dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:+'
}
```

But in my external library folder I have this folder:

```
support-v4-21.0.0-rc1 //note the 21
```

I solved the above problem by changing the dependency to:

```
dependencies {
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:20.+' //20 used less than available strange but works
}
```

Note: you might also need to download api level lower than the currently available in Android Studio for some library and projects for this to work properly.

Comment: This does seem to be the fundamental issue: "wherever you see 'com.android.support:support'" ... "make sure you have the up-to-date value"  That's about the size of it!

Answer (score 6):

I also had the same issue and changing following helped me:

from:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:+'
```

to:

```
dependencies {
 compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:20.0.0'
}
```

Comment: it;s not a code. you need to make this change in your build.gradle file.

Answer (score 5):

I solved the problem by editing the line below in **build.gradle** and it works! **:-)**

adding version  **20.+'**

From

```
 dependencies {
        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'
    }
```

To

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:20.+'
}
```

Comment: I can't believe it. None of the other answers above worked for me, except this one. Thank you!!! Note, I had to change both my `v4` and `v7` support files to the `:20.+`.

Answer (score 5):

```
compile('com.android.support:support-v4:19.1.0'){
    force = true
}
```

Helped me, taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24444196/android-studio-gradle-doesnt-compile-the-specified-version)

Answer (score 4):

You have to configure all the supports and appcompat libraries with version 19.+

If the recommendation of leave the support library with the 19.+ version doesn't works you can try the next tip in your AndroidManifest file.

First add this code:

```
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
```

And then, at the application level (not inside application!)

```
<uses-sdk tools:node="replace" />
```

Answer (score 4):

I make all of the solutions in here with no result, so i look in another place and i found a way to trick the IDE, so you have to put a line in the Mainfest to make the Gradle use a different one, the one that you put on build.gradle the line is:

```
<uses-sdk tools:node="replace" />
```

just it, and it work.

I hope it helps.

Comment: remember to add: `xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"` in the `<manifest>`-tag

Answer (score 3):

You need to remove from build.gradle `compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:+'`

Answer (score 3):

Here's the new bug filed for this btw https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=72430

Assuming you are using the Support Repository, the workaround is to comment or remove the line

21.0.0-rc1
in the local Maven repo listing file at /extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support-v4/maven-metadata.xml

Answer (score 3):

For me the issue like this is solved by changing the

```
minSdkVersion 14
```

In the build.gladdle file and use the one that is specified in the error message

but the issue was

```
Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 14 cannot be smaller than version 15 declared in library
```

So I changed from 14 to 15 in the build.gladdle file and it works

give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

Just target the required `minSdkVersion` i.e change to the needed one
In my case `minSdkVersion` was `14`.

Changing to `minSdkVersion` `16` solved the issue

```
compileSdkVersion 29
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "e.futaaapp"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

compileSdkVersion 29
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "e.futaaapp"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget, you should edit build.gradle in 'app' subfolder of your project, not in project's folder. I've lost a working day trying to solve a problem with version "L".

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting the **build** folder(s) in your project and resync your gradle project to rebuild it.  Also, like others have said in this post - instead of doing something like this:

```
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.+'
```

do this:

```
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.1.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @Murtuza. Your answer helped me to solve my problem but in my case

`compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:19.+` also, along with

`compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.+'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.+'`

from
`compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:+'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v7:+'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:+'`
Hope this might help some one

Answer (score 0):

I have the second solution:

1. unzip `https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/16403954/android-21.zip` to `sdk\platforms\`
2. change build.gradle like

   ```
   compileSdkVersion 21
   buildToolsVersion "20.0.0"

   defaultConfig {
       applicationId "package.name"
       minSdkVersion 10
       targetSdkVersion 21
       versionCode 1
       versionName "1.0"
   }
   ```
3. add

   ```
   <uses-sdk tools:node="replace" />
   ```

   in Manifest with `xmlns:tools="schemas.android.com/tools"`;
4. Go to `sdk\extras\android\m2repository\com\android\support\support-v4\21.0.0-rc1\`

unpack **support-v4-21.0.0-rc1.aar** and edit **AndroidManifest.xml** like

from

```
<uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="L"
        android:targetSdkVersion="L" />
```

to

```
<uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="4"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />
```

P.S. You can do this with all support libraries that need.

Comment: I have changed "L" and restarted android studio but getting same issue  when build project (ctrl+f9)

Answer (score 0):

I have some projects where I prefer to target L.MR1(SDKv22) and some projects where I prefer KK(SDKv19). Your result may be different, but this worked for me.

```
// Targeting L.MR1 (Android 5.1), SDK 22
android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 22
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    // google support libraries (22)
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:21.0.3'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:21.0.3'
}



// Targeting KK (Android 4.4.x), SDK 19
android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19.1"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 19
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    // google libraries (19)
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.1+'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.1+'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:+'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:+'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Android Studio 1.1.0: File - Project Structure - Tab Flavors - Select Min SDK Version which is higher than in Manifest

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that worked for me is this:

In project.properties, I changed:

cordova.system.library.1=com.android.support:support-v4:+
to
cordova.system.library.1=com.android.support:support-v4:20.+

Answer (score 0):

You just change Minimum API Level from `Build Settings -> Player Settings -> Other Settings -> Minimum SDK Level` to some higher version.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to let the Android Studio fix the issue.

I did the below, and it worked fine.

1. Open your project in Android Studio, errors will be popup, if there is a link given to fix it click on it.
2. Re-open your project in Android Studio, errors will be popup, there will be a link this time if it's not given in the Step 1, click on the given link to fix it.

Note that both operations took several minutes of time, but fixed all issues.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution: Manifest merger failed Attribute application@ppComponentFactory ...**

If you are using any latest & greatest Firebase libraries or any other libraries, those are actually using AndroidX instead of android.support then you might have the issue as Manifest merger failed!! So, in this case, your project needs to migrate to AndroidX. So follow the link:
https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android#update_-_june_17_2019

Or watch this video. 
https://youtu.be/RgveQ4AY1L8
Thank you.

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but you should ensure your answer is also useful without it. It's better to add context around the link and describe the most relevant part of the tutorial you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable.

Comment: Nice to hear from you #Joey. Let me add some extra description. Thanks.