# The latest support library v4 requires minSdk(API 20, L Preview)?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-5.0-lollipop

I'm trying to run a project with the Android Studio 0.8.0 beta and the latest tools, it requires API 20, so it fails to run on the device with API 19

Any ideas?

Comment: Tools do not require any API level. Projects do.

Comment: Yeah you are right, I mean this is related to the latest tools, because it appeared right after I installed it

Comment: possible duplicate of [Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 14](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24438170/manifest-merger-failed-uses-sdkminsdkversion-14)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you configured your gradle settings to compile the latest version of

- 'com.android.support:support-v4:+'
- 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'

then the RC will be downloaded, which requires the L - Preview.

See the Answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24438170/manifest-merger-failed-uses-sdkminsdkversion-14).

Use

- 'com.android.support:support-v4:20.+'
- 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:20.+'

**everywhere** in your project instead.

Comment: is there a solution for Eclipse too, that won't require minSdkVersion to be so high?

Answer (score 6):

The problem still arises with transitive dependencies. Gradle offers a way to force the usage of a specific version of a dependency.

For example you can add something like:

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy {
        force 'com.android.support:support-v4:20.+'
        force 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:20.+'
    }
}
```

to your build.gradle.

If you want to learn more about gradle resolution strategies refer to this guide http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.artifacts.ResolutionStrategy.html

I found this while reading the corresponding issue which I will link [here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=72430)