# Android Studio gradle doesn't compile the specified version

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I've been developing this small project for some days now but suddenly today, Android Studio started to give me this error

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 14 cannot be smaller than version 14 declared in library com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.0-rc1
```

I understood that it is because it's trying to compile the library of Android-L. The version I want it to compile is the old version but it won't. It keeps giving me the above error no matter which version I enter. Here is the dependencies.

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:20.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:20.+'
}
```

**UPDATE**

I just installed Android Studio Beta and changed my dependencies to the one Eugen suggested below. But syncing the project gives the same error no matter which version of appcompat, support version I specify. It gives this error every single time I sync

```
uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 14 cannot be smaller than version L declared in library com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.0-rc1
```

My updated dependencies

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.+'
}
```

**UPDATE 2**

I don't think I understand the dependencies system of Android Studio correctly. I just removed both the appcompat and support from the dependencies and it still gives me the same error. Do I have to remove the initially included libraries from somewhere?

**build.gradle**

*note - I added those two libraries back in again and tried syncing, just in case. But no chenges.

```
apply plugin: 'android'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19.1.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "taz.starz.footynews"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.+'
    compile project(':ParallaxScroll')
    compile files('src/main/libs/Header2ActionBar-0.2.1.jar')
    compile 'com.arasthel:gnavdrawer-library:+'
    compile 'com.koushikdutta.ion:ion:1.2.4'
}
```

**Top level build.gradle**

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.12.+'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
```

Comment: It looks like you have multimodal project. What id your parent build.gradle?

Comment: You mean the top level build.gradle file?

Comment: What are dependencies for parallaxscroll project?

Comment: Yes, top level build.gradle

Comment: It's build.gradle file doesn't contain any dependencies and there's no .jar files either. So I'm assuming it doesn't have any dependencies?

Comment: I added the parent build.gradle file to the OP

Comment: I found `support_annotations_21_0_0_rc1.xml` and `support_v4_21_0_0_rc1.xml` insid .idea/libraries. Shall I try deleting them?

Comment: I just deleted them and rebuilt the project, but the same 2 appeared back again.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

**UPDATE:** Found the real fix for my case. Make sure none of your dependencies are silently including support-v4 r21 by doing this in your `build.gradle`:

```
compile("com.blahblah:blah:123") {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module:'support-v4'
}
```

You can add the `exclude` to all libraries, then remove one-by-one until you figure out which one was pulling in `support-v4` and giving you the error. And leave `exclude` on that one.

---

There is a new bug filed here: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=72430

Assuming you are using the Support Repository, the workaround is to comment or remove the line

```
<version>21.0.0-rc1</version>
```

in the local Maven repo listing file at `<android-sdk>/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support-v4/maven-metadata.xml`

Comment: Thanks a lot dude. Solved the problem. I'm guessing after Google resolve this issue, I'll have to go back and enter it back in the file?

Comment: Great :) I use standalone android sdk so don't have such issue. Good to know!

Comment: Commenting out that line fixes it for now.

Comment: The same can be caused by `appcompat-v7`, so you should also try `exclude group: 'com.android.support', module:'appcompat-v7'` when it doesn't work with `support-v4`.

Answer (score 24):

With the last updates, using this:

```
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:20.+'
```

or

```
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:+'
```

you are using the support lib in **L-preview**.

These support libs are declaring `minSdkVersion L`.

You have to force the `minSdkVersion` to be 'L' (check the doc)

This is because these APIs are not final. It is a way to prevent installing the apps on a final API 21 device or publishing it on the store using support lib 21-r1.

Using

```
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.1.0'
```

you are using the "old" support library 19.1.0.

Comment: I understood this halfway through and tried entering `compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.1.+'` inside dependencies but it still compiled the newest version (for some reason). TalkLittle's answer worked although I suspect it's not the best solution.

Comment: try to clean the cache and resync the project

Comment: compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:20.+' doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 24):

I had the same issue as one of my dependencies had specified 'support-v7:+' as a dependency.  I was able to track this down using `gradle dependencies`

Gradle provides a way to [force resolution](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.artifacts.dsl.DependencyHandler.html#N15F3A) to a specific version.  I ended up having this in my `build.grade`:

```
compile('com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.1.0') {
    // really use 19.1.0 even if something else resolves higher
    force = true 
}
```

Answer (score 9):

```
compile('com.android.support:support-v4:19.1.0'){
    force = true
}
```

This worked for me

Answer (score 1):

That is correct. The new support library is not compatible (yet) with old Android versions.

Change your gradle to:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.1.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.1.+'
}
```

I hope your still have something like this:

```
android {
  compileSdkVersion 19
  buildToolsVersion '19.1.0'

  defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 19
 }
}
```

Comment: I changed it to the one you said, but it gives this (I just now installed AS Beta so it shows the error in a slightly different way)
 uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 14 cannot be smaller than version L declared in library com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.0-rc1

Comment: And yes, the compileSdkVersion, minSdkVersion, etc are defined correctly.

Comment: Did you cheange this `com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.+`? Did you synchronized project with gradle file after?

Comment: After I changed it it requested to Sync and I did and it gave me the same error. Am I doing it wrong? Do I have to synchronise it manually?

Comment: I don't think I understand the system of the Android Studio correctly. Can you see my update (2) and give me an answer Eugen?

Comment: Can you post your entire build.gradle file?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time dude, I resolved the issue by following TalkLittle's answer.

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the error:

> Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
>
> > Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 1 cannot be smaller than version 4 declared in library
> >     C:\Users\Igor\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\samples\android-21_1\legacy\ApiDemos\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\support-v4\21.0.3\AndroidManifest.xml
> >       Suggestion: use tools:overrideLibrary="android.support.v4" to force
> >     usage

Then I resolved it by putting the following in my **defaultConfig** gradle block:

```
minSdkVersion 15
targetSdkVersion 21
```

Comment: I'm getting the same error, and this didn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

In Android SDK Manager install "Android Support Repository" from "extra" group. It helps me. When I added "exclude group: 'com.android.support', module:'support-v4'" build was completed, but some other errors was occured