# For Android Material support libraries, where can I find CardView and RecyclerView?

Tags: android, android-support-library

I cannot find RecyclerView, Palette or CardView in the support libraries. Emulators responds with a "Class Not Found" error.

How can I fix an error like this?

Answer (score 74, accepted):

You require these libraries in your build.gradle.

```
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:+'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:+'
compile 'com.android.support:palette-v7:+'
```

Source:
http://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/297xli/howto_use_the_v21_support_libs_on_older_versions/

Comment: It's important to note that these support libs currently force the minSdkVersion to L for your app, unless you use the first workaround specified in the source link.

Comment: @EddieRingle I had success with explicitly setting the required support-v4 library version to `20.+` as described in http://stackoverflow.com/a/24438395/1237813 . The new widgets are available and it does not cause the bug.

Comment: Actually, I am using "minSdkVersion 14" in the gradle.build and it is working fine as far as I know. However; targetSdkVersion must be "L", compileSdkVersion must be "android-L" and  buildToolsVersion must be  "20.0.0".

Comment: How do I use those new features on android projects via Ecilpse?

Comment: Cant u use this on sdk lower then L?

Comment: It has been added that "Please don't use + for builds". Please use stable version, otherwise it can lead to unpredictable builds.