# Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 8 cannot be smaller

Tags: java, android

The problem is..

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
```

> Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 8 cannot be smaller than version L declared in library com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.0-rc1

The code in build.gradle

```
   apply plugin: 'android'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "20.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.androidexample.gcm"
        minSdkVersion 8
        targetSdkVersion 16
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:+'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
    //compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:20.0.0'
    //compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:5.0.77'

}
```

Code in the AndroidManifest is ..

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.androidexample.gcm"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <!-- GCM requires Android SDK version 2.2 (API level 8) or above. -->
    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="16" />

    <!-- Main activity. -->
    <application
        android:name="com.androidexample.gcm.Controller"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <!-- Register Activity -->
        <activity
            android:name="com.androidexample.gcm.RegisterActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.DELETE" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />  
                <data android:scheme="com.idrivecare.familypro" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>


        <!-- Main Activity -->
        <activity
            android:name="com.androidexample.gcm.MainActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
        </activity>

        <receiver
            android:name="com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
            <intent-filter>

                <!-- Receives the actual messages. -->
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <!-- Receives the registration id. -->
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

                <category android:name="com.androidexample.gcm" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <service android:name="com.androidexample.gcm.GCMIntentService" />
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    </application>

    <!-- GCM connects to Internet Services. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <!-- GCM requires a Google account. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />

    <!-- Keeps the processor from sleeping when a message is received. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

    <!-- Creates a custom permission so only this app can receive its messages. -->
    <permission
        android:name="com.androidexample.gcm.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.androidexample.gcm.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

    <!-- This app has permission to register and receive data message. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

    <!-- Network State Permissions to detect Internet status -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <!-- Permission to vibrate -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />

</manifest>
```

Thank you sir..

Comment: Check this http://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/297xli/howto_use_the_v21_support_libs_on_older_versions/

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you use

```
'com.android.support:support-v4:+'
```

It will suppose it can use 21.x since is the latest version (but not compatible with target less than L)

Change it to

```
'com.android.support:support-v4:20.+'
```

So it will download the latest 20.x version

Comment: Thank you sir.
But now Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 8 cannot be smaller than version 9 declared in library com.google.android.gms:play-services:5.0.77

Help me please.

Comment: Play services 5.0 require api 9. You need the latest version? If not, use an older

Comment: Thank you sir.
I use compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:4.1.32' It work.

Comment: I don't recall having those settings defined anywhere... what file(s) are you referring to?

Comment: @mmcrae Check your build.gradle file

Answer (score 36):

The problem is because your app min sdk is 8 and you selected to use the Google Plus services that requires min sdk 9.

Change the line "**minSdkVersion 8**" to "**minSdkVersion 9**". So, **save it**.

After, **Clean Project** and **Rebuild it**.

Comment: where is that line `min SdkVersion 8` found? I don't recall typing/placing that.

Comment: @mmcrae in app/build.gradle

Answer (score 12):

In my case I changed the code {minSdkVersion 8} inside build.gradle file to {minSdkVersion 9}

```
    defaultConfig {
            applicationId "com.example.npeducations.week1_lab"
            minSdkVersion 9
            targetSdkVersion 23
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
           }
```

Now it works fine

Comment: Thanks. I made the change you suggested and the change in the manifest file, with both changes made it now works.

Comment: I think this te most common problem for this error.

Answer (score 3):

```
<uses-sdk tools:overrideLibrary="your pkg name of libary with conflict" />
```

and add xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" in AndroidManifest.xml

Answer (score 0):

I had to change the my libGDX Android Studio's `android/build.gradle` file so it looked like this when I wanted to integrate Amazon Mobile Ads library.

```
android {
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"
    compileSdkVersion 23
    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
            jniLibs.srcDirs = ['libs']
        }

        instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')
    }
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.foo.bar"
        // RBC minSdkVersion 8
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 23
    }
}
...
```

Answer (score -4):

You can run the simply following command.

```
cordova build android -- --minSdkVersion=15
```

It will work for you.