# error import android eclipse project in Android Studio

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.

> Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 8 cannot be smaller than version 9 declared in library [com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0] C:\Users\admin\Desktop\RingtoneApp2\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.google.android.gms\play-services\8.4.0\AndroidManifest.xml
>       Suggestion: use tools:overrideLibrary="com.google.android.gms.all" to force usage

I used the site
http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/migrate.html

Comment: It has been changed minSdkVersion to 9    The same problem

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 8 cannot be smaller](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24718824/manifest-merger-failed-uses-sdkminsdkversion-8-cannot-be-smaller)

Answer (score 2):

You have a library (Play Services) that declares its minSdkVersion to be 9 but your application declares it to be 8. Since the library won't work on API 8, this combination is invalid. Eclipse didn't check for this but Android Studio does.

Answer (score 0):

First Remove the google play library(in this case com.google.android.gms.play_services), then open manifests --> AndroidManifest.xml and change min sdk version to 9

This Line: `android:minSdkVersion="9"`

Also Change it in your build.gradle of app.. under the defaultConfig