# Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'. - androidstudio

Tags: android

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 8 cannot be smaller than version 9 declared in library [com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.0] C:\Users\tal\AndroidStudioProjects\MyApplication3\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\appcompat-v7\24.2.0\AndroidManifest.xml
    Suggestion: use tools:overrideLibrary="android.support.v7.appcompat" to force usage
```

That is what i get when im trying to run an aplication on a virtual device.
I tried to change what they have asked, but it didnt hellp.

Comment: You need to set `minSdkVersion` to 9 or greater in `build.gradle`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Manifest Merger Fails](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39005131/manifest-merger-fails)

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24718824/manifest-merger-failed-uses-sdkminsdkversion-8-cannot-be-smaller

Comment: Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 8 cannot be smaller than version 9 declared in library [com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.0] C:\Users\tal\AndroidStudioProjects\MyApplication3\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\appcompat-v7\24.2.0\AndroidManifest.xml
 Suggestion: use tools:overrideLibrary="android.support.v7.appcompat" to force usage

Comment: The error message gives suggestions about how to fix the problem. Also see the two questions I linked above for more details. If you still have difficulties, please edit this question to explain what you have tried and what the outcome was.

Comment: i still didn't understand what i need to do.. i change my version to 8 and 10 and that didnt work..

Comment: What exactly did you change? Which file did you make this change in? What error are you getting now?

Comment: my mistake i edit the code its look like that now

Comment: apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.tal.buzorgiproject"
        minSdkVersion 10
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'

Comment: }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.0'
}

Comment: Please edit your question so that you can give proper formatting

Comment: i edited the question

Comment: What error do you get now?

Comment: Error:(1) Error parsing XML: encoding specified in XML declaration is incorrect

Comment: Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
 com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException:

Comment: This looks like a completely different error. Please post a new question.

Comment: i edit see if you know how fix that.. if no i post new :) thx

Comment: Completely replacing the question each time is not helpful. Please post a new question for your new error message.