# How to solve Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'

Tags: android

I keep getting this error everytime I try to build. Any solutions? I have tried searching up countless options but have achieved nothing.

The error I faced:

[image: The Error Here]

Here are the gradle codes [gradle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G2QCD.png)

Comment: post your build gradle codes , i think you are declaring sdk versions wrongly ..

Comment: The error is just above the line highlighted. Try setting minSdkVersion 14 in your app.gradle and compile.

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24718824/manifest-merger-failed-uses-sdkminsdkversion-8-cannot-be-smaller

Comment: change minSdkVersion to 14

Comment: Use minimum sdk version 14 in your app module.

Answer (score 2):

Google play services have stopped supporting SDK versions lower than 14. So, you have to set your minSdkVersion to 14.
In `defaultConfig` set the minimum `SDK 14` for using play-service.
Like this:

```
defaultConfig {
       .....
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

**com.google.gms:play-services:11.0.1**

uses minimum

> SDK 14 
>   and you Used minimum SDK 11
>   so Change it

```
defaultConfig {
       .....
        //minSdkVersion 11 to
          minSdkVersion 14
       ....
    }
```

Comment: I've changed it then got this new error Error:(3) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Borderless.Colored'.