# Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 14 cannot be smaller than version L

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio, repository, android-5.0-lollipop

I've followed [following topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24438170/manifest-merger-failed-uses-sdkminsdkversion-14) with no result. Decided to `find|grep` all `support-v4` contents in project folder and remove them. Every time I make and run project it respons with:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 14 cannot be smaller than version L declared in library com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.0-rc1
```

My `build.gradle` from module is:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "20.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.android"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 17
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:4.2.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'
}
```

`build.gradle` from project root:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.12.2'

    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

I know it is similar topic but suggested sollution does not fit this case. 
I would appreciate any explanation of this all dependencies structure which might have impact in that problem.

When we `find|grep` for "support-v4" inside this project folder it looks like this:

```
...\.gradle\1.12\taskArtifacts\fileSnapshots.bin                                                    
...\.gradle\1.12\taskArtifacts\taskArtifacts.bin                                                    
...\.idea\workspace.xml                                                                             
...\.idea\libraries\support_v4_21_0_0_rc1.xml                                                       
...\app\app.iml                                                                                     
...\app\build.gradle                                                                                                   
...\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeResources\debug\merger.xml                             
...\build\intermediates\model_data.bin
```

Regards

Comment: what did you try changing? did you actually put in `compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:20.0.0'` or did you change you `v7` library to that? hopefully you changed your `v7` library

Comment: Why v7 lib should cause v4 problem, is there any connection between them when sync/build project?

Comment: `v7` library includes `v4` library

Comment: Ok, so v4 import is useless if we do import v7, yes ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'
```

with:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.1.0'
```

In general, do not use `+` wildcards at the top version level. If you wanted to use `19.1.+`, or even `19.+`, I wouldn't argue (though others would).

Comment: AFAIK, further problem mostly occurs with :support-v4 not v7, but still no idea how to solve it..

Comment: @Kuba: `appcompat-v7` depends upon `support-v4`. Hence, pulling in too-new of a version of `appcompat-v7` will pull in too-new of a version of `support-v4`.