# following class not found LoginButton facebook android

Tags: android, facebook, intellij-idea, sdk

I'm using IntelliJ and I try to use the Facebook SDK in my Android Project. I have added the facebook SDK like a module in my project. I can import the facebook package correctly(for example com.facebook.session) in my java classes. But when I try to use a LoginButton in my xml files I have this error:

The following classes could not be found:

com.facebook.widget.LoginButton

Why?Please help! I have tried all the possible way. I have edited also the gradle files. 
How can I solve?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably you have an ***error***, verify in bottom panel. When you have a problem, the compilation is not completed. So you can't use the facebook widgets

If you have a problem with minSdkVersion you can check this

[Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 14 cannot be smaller than version L](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25536612/manifest-merger-failed-uses-sdkminsdkversion-14-cannot-be-smaller-than-versio)