# Android studio : android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout could not be found

Tags: android

After importing the demo from http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html, the **android studio** automatically makes it **Gradle-configured** . 
At first, it's dependency part in `build.gradle`:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:+'

}
```

And the above causes error.

Followed the solution ([Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 14](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24438170/manifest-merger-failed-uses-sdkminsdkversion-14)), I change it to

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:20.0.0'

}
```

and it works. Then I can build and run the app.

However, the code shows 'cannot resolve symbol R ‘, 'cannot resolve symbol DrawerLayout' and so on. And I then found errors in `activity_main.xml`:

```
android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout could not be found
```

I have specify the dependency of `android.support.v4` , and why the drawerlayout cannot be found?

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.3'