# Manifest merger failed : minSdkVersion connot be different than version L

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-5.0-lollipop

I got this error :

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 21 cannot be different than version L declared in library C:\Users\usere\AndroidStudioProjects\p1\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\support-v4\21.0.0-rc1\AndroidManifest.xml
```

Here is an extract of manifest :

And here is the build.gradle file :

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

    android {
        compileSdkVersion 21
        buildToolsVersion '21.0.0'

        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "com.frisbeeeapp.frisbeee"
            minSdkVersion 21
            targetSdkVersion 21
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
        }
        buildTypes {


 release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image-loader:1.9.3'
    compile 'com.makeramen:roundedimageview:1.5.0'
    compile 'com.iangclifton.android:floatlabel:1.0'
    //compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:5.0.89'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.1.71'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:20.0.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.+'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.3.2'
    compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
    compile 'com.daimajia.slider:library:1.0.9@aar'
    compile 'com.melnykov:floatingactionbutton:1.0.3'
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 14](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24438170/manifest-merger-failed-uses-sdkminsdkversion-14)

Comment: I think what it is saying is that `compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:20.0.+' compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.+'` need to use the same version. i.e.  you are using version 20 and 21

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, choose *either* `support-v4` *or* `support-v13`. Do not have both, as they have most of the same classes. Given your `minSdkVersion` of 21, I would suggest that you use `support-v13`.

Then, for whichever one of those you choose, make sure the version is 21 or higher (e.g., `21.0.+`).