# Minimum sdk for Facebook sdk

Tags: android, facebook

I had the common errors like when trying to setup the fb sdk such as ANDROID_BUILD_SDK_TOOLS ERROR and getbootclasspath() method error

but some of the solutions that people posted on SO has the minimum sdk as 14, instead of 9 (which is shown on the fb's guide). Now in my app's build.gradle file, if I use minSdkVersion 9 instead of 14, it wont work and it will say:

Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.

> Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 9 cannot be smaller than version 14 declared in library

I have researched, but couldn't find the solution for using 9 because I want to support the app on Gingerbread.

Comment: this solution does not work: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24438170/manifest-merger-failed-uses-sdkminsdkversion-14

Answer (score 3, accepted):

nvm I solved it. All I had to do was put this in the app's manifest file:

```
> <uses-sdk android:targetSdkVersion="22" android:minSdkVersion="9"
>               tools:overrideLibrary="com.facebook"/>
```

Answer (score 5):

If anyone has this kind of error

"uses-sdk:minSdkVersion **14** cannot be smaller than version **15**"

Just downgrade FacebookSDK to 4.5.0

```
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.5.0'
```