# Use library that require higher minSdkVersion than the current minSdkVersion

Tags: android, android-studio, android-manifest, android-4.1-jelly-bean

I am using [Uber](https://github.com/uber/rides-android-sdk/) SDK which is designed to work with Android SDK 16. My current minSdkVersion is 14. I can use it like -

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
  //Call specific function
}
```

and put xml in folder `layout-v16`. But manifest merger failed

```
uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 14 cannot be smaller than version 16 declared in library
```

How can I solve this ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24438170/manifest-merger-failed-uses-sdkminsdkversion-14

Comment: All answers tell you to use correct compile version of support library. It doesnt answer my question.

Answer (score 10):

You have to declare in your manifest:

```
<uses-sdk tools:overrideLibrary="com.uber.sdk.android.rides" />
```

In this case you can ignore `minSdk` issue.

Use `xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"` in manfiest tag.