# Cordova/Phonegap Build error code 1 using admobpro

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins

I have seen lots of posts about this error code but mine does not seem to the same as the others that I have read up on lately.

Here is the error I am getting when trying to build my project.

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

 Execution failed for task ':processDebugManifest'.> Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 11 cannot be smaller than version 14 declared in library [android:CordovaLib:unspecified:debug] C:\Users\CGZ\Desktop\TestAdd\platforms\android\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\android\CordovaLib\unspecified\debug\AndroidManifest.xml
 Suggestion: use tools:overrideLibrary="org.apache.cordova" to force usage
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
```

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 12.759 secs

```
Error: Error code 1 for command: cmd with args: /s,/c,"C:\Users\CGZ\Desktop\TestAdd\platforms\android\gradlew cdvBuildDebug -b C:\Users\CGZ\Desktop\TestAdd\platforms\android\build.gradle -Dorg.gradle.daemon=true-Pandroid.useDeprecatedNdk=true"
```

If I remove the plugin from the config.xml file then it compiles the build fine. 
    `<preference name="android-build-tool" value="gradle" />`
    `<gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-admobpro" source="npm" />`

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24438170/manifest-merger-failed-uses-sdkminsdkversion-14

Comment: try this `<preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="10" />`