# Wikitude: uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 14 cannot be smaller than version 15 declared in library [:wikitudesdk:]

Tags: android, cordova, wikitude

I'm trying to build a cordova android app with wikitude plugin. When I build the project using `cordova build`, I got an error:
`Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 14 cannot be smaller than version 15 declared in library [:wikitudesdk:]`. I tried several answers here: [Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 14](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24438170/manifest-merger-failed-uses-sdkminsdkversion-14?rq=1), but they didn't solve my problem.

Currently, my portion of build.gradle looks like:

```
dependencies {
    // do not use dynamic updating.
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:20.+' 
}
```

and I changed my AndroidManifest.xml to force the minsdkversion set to be 15:

```
<uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="15"
        android:targetSdkVersion="23" />
```

anybody has ideas to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, my bad, I shouldn't change the:
`~\<Project>\platforms\android\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\wikitudesdk\AndroidManifest.xml`.
Instead, I just changed the version in `~\<Project>\platforms\android\AndroidManifest.xml` and it works. Also, there's no need to change the dependencies in build.gradle if you are using the latest version. It should be a quick and easy fix.