# Manifest merger failed (firebase)

Tags: android, build.gradle

I'm first time working with firebase and having a tough time with dependencies issues.

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'. >
>   Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 15 cannot be smaller
>   than version 16 declared in library [com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:2.3.0]
>   Suggestion: use tools:overrideLibrary="com.firebase.ui" to force usage

Comment: show `build.gradle`

Comment: The android section, particularly minSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion in the build.gradle file

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 14](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24438170/manifest-merger-failed-uses-sdkminsdkversion-14)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change your minSdkVersion from 15 to 16 in your app `build.gradle`