# Manifest Merger Failed Error: Gradle Version Issue

Tags: android, android-studio, android-manifest

I am trying to create a Tinder-style swipe left/swipe right feature. But when I added the dependencies into my code I got this manifest error:

> Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 15 cannot be smaller than version 16 declared in library [com.mindorks:placeholderview:0.7.1] /Users/cassandracampbell/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/placeholderview-0.7.1.aar/e4aa1d0fe45df90e4bd68b2aac33a24e/AndroidManifest.xml as the library might be using APIs not available in 15
>       Suggestion: use a compatible library with a minSdk of at most 15,
>           or increase this project's minSdk version to at least 16,
>           or use tools:overrideLibrary="com.mindorks.placeholderview" to force usage (may lead to runtime failures)

How can I fix this?

Comment: do change in build.gradle minSdkVersion 16 and check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24438170/manifest-merger-failed-uses-sdkminsdkversion-14

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to error message:

> Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 15 cannot be smaller than version 16 declared in library [com.mindorks:placeholderview:0.7.1]

You need to change your **minSdkVersion** 14 to 16 in your `app/build.gradle` . I.e.

```
defaultConfig {
    ...
    minSdkVersion 16
    ...
}
```

Comment: Please accept my answer if it helped you solve your problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You are using this library com.mindorks:placeholderview:0.7.1 whose minimum sdk is 16. So in order to use this library your minimum sdk should also be 16. Just change the minimum sdk in your gradle to 16 and it will work.