# Android Studio 3.2.1: minSdk(API 23) > deviceSdk(API 22) Wear OS

Tags: android

First of all. I'm quite new to Android development. I'm trying to make a Wear OS app with Android Studio 3.2.1 for my smart watch. My watch has API 22 (Lollipop 5.1), but when creating a new project API 23 is the lowest I can select. So I'm getting the following error when trying to run the app on my smart watch.

[problem image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GnzzS.jpg)

How can I solve this problem? Thanks.

**Update**:

I found this tutorial on the internet:
[Android Wear tutorial](http://www.smartwatch.me/t/tutorial-how-to-develop-android-wear-apps-for-beginners-part-1-setup/684)

An image in the tutorial shows what SDKs to install.
[SDKs to install](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cXQft.jpg)

I need to install the Android Wear SDK for Lollipop. But I don't have these SDKs presented.
[SDKs presented](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8utjC.jpg)

Where can I find the Android Wear SDK for Lollipop?

Comment: minimize your app sdk in gradle file. check  minSdkVersion it would be 23 change it to   minSdkVersion 16//i.e below 22 or change device configuration from AVD Manager and edit device sdk version

Comment: The build window says: Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 16 cannot be smaller than version 23 declared in library [com.android.support:wear:28.0.0]...

Comment: checkhttps://stackoverflow.com/questions/24438170/manifest-merger-failed-uses-sdkminsdkversion-14 and https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/build-faild-in-android-uses-sdk-minsdkversion-16-cannot-be-smaller-than-version-19-declared-in-library/132183